# get a specific input type in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to know how to process this file using `Python 3`:

```
120 11
10213 312
10 3
```

I would do this using `C` with this code:

```
scanf("%d", &t);
while (t--) {
   scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);    
   gcd(a, b);
}
```

Comment: I formatted your code

Comment: Please show some python code of what you have tried